# Fetch vs XMLHttpRequest vs Jquery Ajax

Tags: javascript

Olá. Sei que o method `Fetch` do ES6 é o mais recente. Mas vi no site JSPerf que o `fetch` é o mais lento em relação ao famoso `XmlHttpRequest` do JS Vanilla, e ainda mais lento que o `$.Ajax` do JQuery.

Porque ele é o mais lento se ele é o mais atual? alguém pode me explicar?

Link do teste: [XHR vs jQuery vs fetch](https://jsperf.com/xhr-vs-jquery-ajax-vs-get-vs-fetch)

Obrigado.

Comment: Excutando no Chromium e Firefox no OpenSuse esse teste, `fetch()` foi mais veloz que jQuery em ambos, porém mais lento do que o XHR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) na verdade é JS Vanilla pois não pertence à alguma biblioteca de terceiro como as funções do jQuery e tem a intenção de solucionar alguns problemas do XMLHttpRequest (XHR), que reinou por mais de uma década nas requisições assíncronas no Javascript, como:

- Entrada, saída e estados gerenciados interagindo somente com um único objeto
- Estado baseado em eventos
- Não trabalhar bem com *Promise*

[Fonte](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/03/this-api-is-so-fetching/)

`fetch()` se difere do `jQuery.ajax()` principalmente em duas maneiras:

- A *Promise* retornada do `fetch()` não rejeitará o status do erro HTTP, mesmo que a resposta seja um HTTP 404 ou 500. Em vez disso, ele irá resolver normalmente, e ele somente rejeitará em caso de falha na rede ou se qualquer coisa impedir que o pedido seja concluído.
- Por padrão, a busca não enviará nem receberá cookies do servidor, resultando em solicitações não autenticadas se o site se basear na manutenção de uma sessão de usuário.

O desempenho pode variar entre os browser, visto que cada um terá sua [implementação](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#fetch-method) de `window.fetch` (ex: V8 da Google ou Spidermonkey da Mozilla).

### Por quê mais lento?

A pricipal razão na diferença em desempenho é devido `fetch()` ter mais opções em relação ao XHR, que podemos encontrar [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). Fazer algo novo não necessariamente significa que deve ser mais veloz, é o que acontece nesse caso - recursos disponiveis parecem que são a prioridade.

---

Outras fontes:

- https://jakearchibald.com/2015/thats-so-fetch/
- https://github.com/github/fetch

Comment: Perfeito cara, muito obrigado!